# Static routes in pimcore not working for more than one parameter

Tags: pimcore

I´d like to definie a static route in pimcore. This works find as long as the route does not have more than one parameter. As soon as I add a seconde one, I get the following error message:

```
You have requested a non-existent parameter "book/".
```

The resulting files looks like this:

```yaml
pimcore:
    staticroutes:
        definitions:
            f4a7a318-1d29-4f58-8a3c-d204d33a207a:
                name: story
                pattern: '/\/stories\/(.*)\/(.*)/'
                reverse: /stories/%book/%title
                controller: 'App\Controller\DefaultController::storiesAction'
                variables: 'book,title'
                defaults: null
                siteId: {  }
                methods: null
                priority: 0
                creationDate: 1635722217
                modificationDate: 1635722280
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Addition: It does not work, even if I follow the examples of the [official documentation](https://pimcore.com/docs/pimcore/current/Development_Documentation/MVC/Routing_and_URLs/Custom_Routes.html#building-urls-based-on-custom-routes): You have requested a non-existent parameter "text_". Did you mean this: "fos_js_routing.request_context_base_url"? (500 Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fiddled around with that a bit and found a solution. In previous versions I was able to use reverse patterns like this: */stories/%book/%title* where book and title are the variables. However, it seems that the logic has changed here a bit. The following works now: **/stories/%%book/%%title**